# How to get an Exception in Phpunit with Mock Function

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

I have a function which I need to test. I'm new to mocking objects with Phpunit.

So in Symfony I have a manager class with some functions and so I  need to test the function(s):

```
public function preSendMessage()
    {
        // Check send notification value
        $this->sendSmsNotifications              = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('send_sms_notifications');
        $this->disableNightTimeNotifications     = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('disable_night_time_sms_notifications');
        $this->smsStartHour                      = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('sms_start_hour');
        $this->smsEndHour                        = $this->kernel->getContainer()->getParameter('sms_end_hour');
    }

public function sendMessage($recipientNumber, $message, $communicationLog)
    {
        $this->preSendMessage();

        // Assign extra data
        $this->communicationLog            = $communicationLog;
        $this->communicationLog['created'] = new \DateTime('now');

        // Unable to send sms because sms notifications hasn't turn on
        if (empty($this->sendSmsNotifications) || !$this->sendSmsNotifications) {
            return true;
        }
        // Check recipient number
        if (empty($recipientNumber)) {
            throw new SmsException("Number empty", 0);
        }

        //Clean up recipient number, remove spaces.
        $recipientNumber = str_replace(' ', '', $recipientNumber);

        if (strlen($recipientNumber) > 11 || strlen($recipientNumber) < 8) {
            // Log Errors
            $this->communicationLog['status'] = 'fail';
            $this->communicationLog['error']  = 'Invalid mobile number, must be between 10 and 11 integers long';
            $this->logSms();

            throw new SmsException("Invalid mobile number, must be between 10 and 11 integers long", 0);
        }

        if (strpos($recipientNumber, "04") === 0) {
            $mobileIntFormat = "61".substr($recipientNumber, 1);
        } elseif (strpos($recipientNumber, "02") === 0) {
            $mobileIntFormat = "64".substr($recipientNumber, 1);
        } elseif (strpos($recipientNumber, "07") === 0) {
            $mobileIntFormat = "44".substr($recipientNumber, 1);
        } else {
            $this->communicationLog['status'] = 'fail';
            $this->communicationLog['error']  = 'Invalid Number';
            $this->logSms();

            throw new SmsException("Invalid Number", 0);
        }

        // check if to save for later
        if (!empty($this->disableNightTimeNotifications) && $this->disableNightTimeNotifications == true && strpos($recipientNumber, "07") !== 0) {
            $currentHour = intval(date('G'));

            if ($currentHour >= $this->smsEndHour || $currentHour < $this->smsStartHour) {
                // Log SMS
                 $this->communicationLog['status'] = 'queued';
                 $this->logSms();

                if (!empty($this->communicationLog)) {
                    // Get Entity Manager
                    $this->addIntoCommunicationLogs($this->communicationLog);
                }

                return true;
            }
        }


        // execute request
        $methodResponse = $this->transmitObject->SMS($mobileIntFormat, $body, $this->senderName);

        // parse response into xml object
        $xml = @simplexml_load_string($methodResponse);

        if (empty($xml) || !is_object($xml) || (string) $xml->data->result != 'queued') {
            if (!is_object($xml)) {
                $this->communicationLog['status'] = 'fail';
                $this->communicationLog['error']  = "Message was not added: Object Missing";
                $this->logSms();

                throw new SmsException("Message was not added: Object Missing", 0);
            } else {
                $errorMsg = $this->getSmsErrorMessage($xml, $methodResponse);

                $this->communicationLog['status'] = 'fail';
                $this->communicationLog['error']  = $errorMsg;
                $this->logSms();

                throw new SmsException($errorMsg, 0);
            }
        }

        // Log SMS
        $this->communicationLog['status'] = (!empty($this->communicationLog['error'])) ?  'fail' : 'sent';
        $this->logSms();

        if (!empty($this->communicationLog)) {
            $this->updateCommunicationLog();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

So as you might imagine, I have quite a few scenarios which I need to test using mocking.

- Number is not valid.
- SMS template not valid.
- Data passed in will cause error.
- SMS template parsing error SMS gateway goes away.

So I have tried this in test file:

```
public function testMobileNumberNotValid()
{
    $inputData = array(
        'brand_id' => '1',
        'request_id' => '2600060',
        'original_number' => '0000000',
        'recipient_number' => 'INPUTYOUROWNPHONENUMBER',
        'message' => "Hi dfgfd NOTEBOOK has been accepted at",
        'event_name' => 'some.event',
        'type' => 'sms',
        'server' => ''
    );

    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder(SmsManager::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods([
            'toString',
            'logSms',
            'preSendMessage',
            'sendMessage'
        ])//this only to make sure that we wont mock any other objects
        ->getMock();

    $stub->expects($this->once())
        ->method('sendMessage')
        ->will($this->returnSelf());
    $stub->sendMessage('',$inputData['message'],$inputData);
}
```

As you see in the test function that I have not passed the `recipentNumber` so it will not throw the Exception which should be thrown . So can you help me where I'm wrong? I want to test each scenario of function `sendMessage()`.

Comment: You are mocking the class which you are testing. Mocking is supposed for arguments of class (mostly to mock dependency injection). Mocked objects methods are dummy - original object doesn't get called.

Comment: so can you explain how to test above function. ?

Comment: @truesource: What about just ignoring your current implementation and start with writing tests from scratch. Can you imagine how the code would change then? So just renamed this method to `....Old` and start writing tests. In the end throw the old function away.